# Arcgis : zooming it in a certain angle

Tags: android, arcgis

How do i zoom it in arcgis map at a certain angle for android?
Sorry , im quite new to it  .. Thanks

This are my codes . i also tried implementing it below  zoom to resoulution but it doesnt work.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    // Retrieve the map and initial extent from XML layout
    mMapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.map);

    /* create a @ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer */
    tileLayer = new ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer(

            "http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer");

            // Add tiled layer to MapView
            mMapView.addLayer(tileLayer);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you see your tiled layer on the android simulator or on device? If yes then you have done well so far. Just add these lines below the `mMapView.addLayer(tileLayer);` to achieve `zoomTo`

```
Point zoomtopoint = getCenter();
mMapView.zoomTo(zoomtopoint, 1.0);
```